# Rename folder/file in blender file browser?

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut, file-browser

Is it possible to rename a folder in the blender file browser? How about a file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. Simply hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the file or folder you would like to rename.